# Mac android studio Show only grade building

Tags: macos, android-studio-2.3

[image of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI7mC.png)

*android studio showing only grade building from a long time, I am unable to create the project in android studio 2.3.3 on my Mac*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had the same problem, First check your internet connectivity because gradle needs Internet while building, Second if your internet connection is working well then try this - goto File-> Invalidate and restart select first option from a dialog "Invalidate and restart", this option will restart your android studio and clear all caches.